# Unexpected appearance

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be the word for something that is opposite its *appearance*? Let me give you an example. Say there is a button that can be pushed which would instantly destroy most of civilization. Let's say that this button was decorated with a picture of a smiley face, or a kitten, or something equally "opposite".

What would be the word for the fact that the button, which would destroy the world, was adorned with the picture of a cute, innocent, kitty cat?

Answer (score 8):

Not a single word, but a very effective description:

> *This together with some **counter-intuitive iconography** means that initially at least it’s not the easiest machine to use.* From a [review of a microwave oven](http://www.trustedreviews.com/samsung-mw76n-b-xeu_Microwave_user-reviews) in 2012.

The same form was used [in 2002 by Dr Dobbs](http://www.drdobbs.com/introducing-dreamweaver-ultradev/184412545) to refer to some menus that posed a challenge to users of the software Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 8):

I think the word *incongruous* is close to what you're looking for. It is [defined as:](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incongruous)

> ***incongruous*** (adjective) — not in harmony or keeping with the surroundings or other aspects of something: *the duffel coat looked incongruous with the black dress she wore underneath*

*The picture of a cute, innocent, kitty cat adorning the button was **incongruous** with the purpose of the button, which was to destroy the world.*

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it is:

*deceptive 

misleading

evil

dangerous

dastardly

treacherous

underhanded*

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **Socio-disguise** comes close to it. There is no single word though.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=socio-disguise

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I cannot seriously imagine an atomic weapon behind a button with the picture of a kitten, the dastardly evil booby-trapped dolls are another matter. The generic word "evil" covers the circumstance. I suppose more fitting words can be found when specific intent is obvious, besides the plain evil trickery.

Answer (score 0):

The kitten sticker is **ironic**. Kittens are harmless; nukes aren't.

Comment: So "ironic" is the word I am looking for? I just didn't think so. Another example I thought of the other day is using a lovely song as the theme music for a horror movie. I don't know why I thought there was another word, I guess I was mistaken. Thanks for the help.